# How to read data from multiple text files or an csv file and create output file

Tags: python

I am new to Python. My requirement is :

File A (text file) :
240
241
and so on

File B (text file) :
250
251
and so on

Want to write a script which will take 1 record at a time from each file above and give output as :

Insert into Table A
Where Num1 = 1st record from file A
and Num2 = 1st record from file B
Update Table A
Where Num1 = 1st record from file A
and Num2 = 1st record from file B

Insert into Table A
Where Num1 = 2nd record from file A
and Num2 = 2nd record from file B
Update Table A
Where Num1 = 2nd record from file A
and Num2 = 2nd record from file B

Thought of making writing the static (Insert into Table A Where Num1) in file c and use it as below while writing final output file :

for open('output.txt','w') as f:
f.write(data from filec + looping data from file A)

Can someone provide solution how can I get outfile data ?

Comment: Please write code in code blocks ([ask]) and make sure to provide a [mre]

Comment: with open('fileA.txt) as t:

Comment: Is this supposed to be outputting an SQL query? If so, you may want to add a tag.

Comment: Yes.. I am trying to create multiple SQL queries for 100 records but the num1 and num2 field is different everytime. so how do i achieve this ? I tried below code :            
with open('fileA.txt') as d:
    lines = d.readlines()

with open('FileB.txt') as d:
    lines1 = d.readlines()

f = 'output.txt'
f1 = open(f, 'w')
for l in lines:
   for l1 in lines1:
        f1.write(l+l1)  -- But doesn't pick 2nd record from file A and File B. It goes in for loop and takes again 1st record

Comment: if each record in each file is placed in a separate line you can loop on the output of the function `readline()` else you just need to know what separates the records in the files and `list(split)` the file based on that to have a list of records in each file.
that's about txt tile, csv files needs the knowledge of pandas library which makes dealing with records much easier by the way

Answer (score 0):

if the file is a text file, then you need the open two files and loop on their lines (I don't recommend using `with open ("file.txt") as t` when dealing with multiple files at once, so if the records are on separate lines you just need:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt")
file2 = open("file2.txt")

for lineOf1, lineOf2 in zip(file1, file2):
```

and here `lineOf1` and `lineOf2` are the records you need

and if the records are not on separate lines just add: `lineOf1.split("the character separates the records on each line")` and you will have a list of records so you can loop on it again

but if you are dealing with csv I recommend having a look at pandas library.

Comment: Thank you so much Mohamed !! It worked fine :)

Comment: @Rohan you're welcome, glad to help. :)